# How to check if a user is authenticated with Devise on an AJAX call in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, devise

I have a button that allows a person to join a group (called a pod in my application).  The button uses remote: true to do an AJAX call.  I have a join table that manages the relationships between users and pods with has_many: though:.  In the join table controller I want to be able to check if the user is authenticated before that user can join a pod.  If not authenticated, the user should be taken to a log in page and then back to the page with all the pods listed.

Right now, I've got the following code in pod_users_controller:

```
  before_action :user_logged_in

  ...

  private

  def user_logged_in
      render :js => "window.location = '#{new_user_session_path}'" unless user_signed_in?
  end
```

In my application controller I have the following code to redirect the user back to the page they were on before authenticating:

```
  def store_location
     session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/ 
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
```

It's kind of works but it feels very flaky.  For example, I have another button which allows you to create a new group with an AJAX bootstrap modal.  I've tried using the same method with before_action :user_logged_in in the pods_controller file. It pops the modal without the form and then redirects.  Or when I click on the join button it will redirect me to the form to create a new pod if I just clicked the "start a pod" button before that.

My question is, is there a better way to do what I'm doing?  How do I redirect to login before the modal pops?  I'm just learning ruby and rails so any best practices would be much appreciated.  Also, this is a total side question but in this approach I have the same method I'm calling "user_logged_in" from two controllers.  Right now I have that method at the bottom of both.  I'm assuming there's a place I can put it to make it accessible by multiple controllers from one place?

Thank you!

I'm on Rails 4.2 and Devise 3.4

Comment: have you tried it by adding `before_action :authenticate_user!` in pod_users_controller

Comment: if u put this in application_controller it will automatically get applied on other controllers

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't do anything.  Here's the server log: Processing by PodUsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"G2MXr6bJhHEkXYUMtJ1s8A1M5sIz2nKCa16VColarOLZxfkfd0Vzs2X3PIPRHaRAvx2kozQAG3QtMiOhyRN+cQ==", "pod_id"=>"83", "commit"=>"Join"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 3):

Devise comes with these helpers: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

That includes the before_action `:authenticate_user!` as well as the `user_signed_in?` helper (almost the same name as yours), which is available throughout the app. You could use `user_signed_in?` to redirect from within a view with ERB or in a controller.

Comment: are you suggesting something like:
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% link_to "Join group", join_group_path %>
<% else %>
<% link_to "Join group", new_user_session %><% end %>.

That feels like a really bloated way to do it

Comment: that would work, or you could use `authenticate_user!` in the `join_group` method of the controller if you want to keep the view a little cleaner.   `<%= link_to "Join group", (user_signed_in? ? join_group_path : new_user_session_path) %>` is another alternative.